# Minimal left margin for centred div

Tags: css, html, margin, center

Is there a "css" way of making a centred div behave as if it had a minimal left margin? I would like a centred div to be centred on a page unless the width of that page is less than a certain value. Something like the following:

```
.centred { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; min-margin-left: 200px; }
```

I know that min-margin-left doesn't exist, but how could I achieve this? Below is an example in pictures. Think that grey border is the browser and blue box is my "centred" div.

[image: Centred when page wide enough]

[image: Left margin when page not wide enough]

Answer (score 1):

For something like this we can use [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

```css
.centred { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .centred { margin-left:200px; }
}
```

In this example, all devices which have a display with under 800px width will be given the 200px `margin-left`.

### Alternative Solution Without Media Queries

An alternative solution to this would be to display your content as a table and give the containing cell a padding of 200px.

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.table {
    display:table; /* Give our .table divider a table display */
    width:100%;    /* Set its width to 100% to fill the screen */
}

.table-cell {
    padding:0 200px;  /* 200px left and right padding, 0 top and bottom */
    display:table-cell; /* Give our .table-cell divider a table-cell display */
    vertical-align:middle; /* Vertically align content to the middle */
}

.content { /* This is our content box */
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#f00;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/vcXKM/2/)**.

If you're unsure what I've done, here's a visualisation (using 50px `padding` rather than 200px):

**Regular Size**

[image: Example of Result]

Notice the effect of the padding when the result window is resized.

Comment: In your 2nd answer:If you're going to wrap the content with padding: 0 200px - ie - 200px on both left and right - then you don't need tables: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vcXKM/3/ - ... but in any case I think the OP only wanted the min-margin on the left...

Comment: @Danield is right, I only wanted the min-margin on the left. What I want to achieve is that the minimum width of the document will be the width of the centred div + the left margin. With your suggestion it will be the width of the div + 2 * left margin. The problem with the media query is that the margin only appears when the content width is less than max-width. This makes the layout "jump" on resize when the content width shrinks below the max-width threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media query's:

```
.centred {
    width: 400px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    .centred {
         margin-left: 200px; 
    }
}
```

Adjust the max-width to what you need.

Comment: min-margin-left isn't a rule

Comment: Woopsie, copy&pasted it from the start post and forgot to delete the min-. I edited my answer.

Comment: NP :D, I think it's amusing that all 3 of us posted the exact same answer in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Stackoverflow junks I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with media rules:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

```
.centred {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .centred {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
}
```